# ecountering leaker window while while trying to pass gps coordinates to webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

i am having problem with my application, i am getting gps location of my android phone then after having the coordinates i wanted to pass that data to my webservice, but i am encountering this errors, where in localhost it is running flawless.

These are the errors i'm getting:

**

```
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906): Activity com.example.projectthesis.LocationPassing has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412dd820 that was originally added here
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.projectthesis.LocationPassing has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412dd820 that was originally added here
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at com.example.projectthesis.LocationPassing$phpconnect.onPreExecute(LocationPassing.java:74)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at com.example.projectthesis.LocationPassing.onCreate(LocationPassing.java:58)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-15 18:43:45.856: E/WindowManager(1906):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**

and this is my class:

**

```
public class LocationPassing extends Activity{
    TextView txtLatitude;
    TextView txtLongitude;

    public static String strLat;
    public static String strLong;

    // ** This declarations was for passing of data to web service
        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        // JSONParser Object creation
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        // url to pass location to web
            private static String url_create_product = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/location_adding.php";
         //private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/TheCalling/location_adding.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
         private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locationpassing);

        txtLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
        txtLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);

        strLat = Double.toString(Mapping2.ILatitude);
        strLong = Double.toString(Mapping2.ILongitude);

        this.txtLatitude.setText(strLat);
        this.txtLongitude.setText(strLong);

        new phpconnect().execute();

    }

    class phpconnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationPassing.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String strLatitude = strLat;
            String strLongitude = strLong;

            String.valueOf(strLatitude);
            String.valueOf(strLongitude);

            // Building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", strLatitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", strLongitude));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Mapping2.class);

                    startActivity(i);
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**

thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a dialog in `onPreExecute` but do not dismiss it in `onPostExecute`.

Your `AysncTask` finishes and `pDialog` goes out of scope (it is destroyed) but the window is still on screen and is therefore leaked.

You also need to dismiss it before starting another activity or calling `finish()`.

Also add this to `onPause()` so that it's dismissed if your activity is forced to the background and redisplay it, if you need to, in `onResume()`

```
@Override
public void onPause(){

    super.onPause();

    if(pDialog != null){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }        

    ...

}
```

Basically, don't leave the dialog on screen if your task finishes or you leave the activity.

Comment: Thank you so much, no window leaked now. :) unfortunately the passing part is just not working. anyway, Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  You might want to click the Tick besides the question to mark it as a correct answer so that others might find it in the future, and I get a small reward for spending some time helping ;)